# Why is SELinux blocking my Zabbix agent's sudo calls?

Tags: centos, selinux, zabbix

I have some Zabbix checks that require sudo. These are the contents of /etc/sudoers.d/zabbix

```
zabbix ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: /bin/yum history
zabbix ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: /bin/needs-restarting
zabbix ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: /sbin/check31
zabbix ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/crm_mon --as-xml
```

When I force check from my Zabbix proxy I get the following permission 
denied error (pacemaker.status uses `/usr/sbin/crm_mon --as-xml`):

```
bash-5.0$ zabbix_get -s my-server -k pacemaker.status
sudo: PAM account management error: System error
sudo: unable to send audit message: Permission denied
```

I verified SELinux is indeed blocking my calls by temporarily setting SELinux in permissive mode.

Then, I tried allowing these calls by going through the following steps.

First, I rotated the audit log as it was full with irrelevant messages from previous issues:

```
service auditd rotate
```

I then removed all dontaudits from the policy:

```
semodule -DB
```

On the Zabbix proxy I triggered the error by executing the `zabbix_get` call as stated above.

From the logs I created an SELinux module and installed it with `semodule`:

```
cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M zabbix-agent
semodule -i zabbix-agent.pp
```

Still, I get the same permission denied error on sending the audit message when I execute `zabbix_get`. I did some research, turning off dontaudits should do the trick and force SELinux to log additional messages to address this issue, but I have and it doesn't work for my situation.

This is the `zabbix-agent.te` file `audit2allow` has built:

```
module zabbix-agent 1.0;

require {
    type zabbix_agent_t;
    type chkpwd_exec_t;
    class unix_dgram_socket create;
    class file execute_no_trans;
    class netlink_audit_socket create;
}

#============= zabbix_agent_t ==============
allow zabbix_agent_t chkpwd_exec_t:file execute_no_trans;
allow zabbix_agent_t self:netlink_audit_socket create;
allow zabbix_agent_t self:unix_dgram_socket create;
```

Comment: I can only point you here: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/selinux-unable-to-send-audit-message-4175591310/

Comment: Probably you are missing nlmsg_relay on the netlink_audit_socket

Comment: When that capability is added, you probably have to do a new round of audit2allow.

Comment: I added nlmsg_relay, which didn't work. I then did a new round of audit2allow as you said, but still no luck :(

Comment: Which centos version exactly?

Comment: CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)

Comment: zabbix-agent 4.0 from repo.zabbix.com?

Comment: And it only happens with the crm_mon command? Did you try other crm commands?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
setsebool -P zabbix_can_network=1
```

if you already allowed the above, then you may try this:

```
yum install policycoreutils-python
semanage permissive -a zabbix_agent_t
```

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue (running a RAID controller check on an selinux enabled machine).

The missing link for me was the:

semodule -DB

to enable some non-audit policies.
Then recapture the policy.

Reference was:https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=62829
It's important to have selinux set to permissive first, when you capture.
Pretty much much like you I did something like (after setting to permissive and capturing and applying policy):

log rotate, remove old log :

```
service auditd rotate
```

semodule -DB (disables no audit rules)

- run the command from zabbix (configuration - hosts - execute once)
- run the following to get the policy file

  grep -i avc /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M policyx
- run

  semodule -i policyx.pp
- run command in Zabbix again to check if it works
- run

  semodule -B

  to enable no-audit rules again.

My sudoers rule looks like:

```
zabbix ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /opt/MegaRAID/storcli/storcli64
```

I tried if the zabbix user (which has nologin shell) could run the command like:

```
su -s /bin/bash -c 'sudo /opt/MegaRAID/storcli/storcli64 /c0 /eall /sall show' zabbix
```

I recommend to try the same for your commands to make sure the execute properly as user zabbix.

I also used restorecon on the sudoers and shadow file, but not sure if that helped.
I also set the zabbix_agent_t context on the script I run, but that might not have had effect.

Last but not least, here is the policy file I applied that did the trick for me, perhaps you can just compile and apply it and see if it works:

```
cat mypolz1.te 

module mypolz1 1.0;

require {
    type zabbix_exec_t;
    type zabbix_agent_t;
    type system_dbusd_t;
    class capability { net_admin sys_admin };
    class dbus send_msg;
    class unix_dgram_socket write;
    class file { execute execute_no_trans };
    class netlink_audit_socket { read write };
}

#============= zabbix_agent_t ==============

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow zabbix_agent_t self:capability net_admin;
allow zabbix_agent_t self:capability sys_admin;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow zabbix_agent_t self:netlink_audit_socket { read write };

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow zabbix_agent_t self:unix_dgram_socket write;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow zabbix_agent_t system_dbusd_t:dbus send_msg;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow zabbix_agent_t zabbix_exec_t:file { execute execute_no_trans };
```

As you can see I had some policies set, perhaps the sysadmin is the one that did the trick ( before I got the command running but no output ).

I think iteration is key, because after every step you will get different issues that the policy apply will then mitigate.
Good luck!